# How to re-add GitHub repo after accidental removal from Careers profile?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, profile-page, github

I have accidentally removed a GitHub project from my Careers 2.0 profile. When I tried to add it again, it was still marked as on my profile and there was no way to add it again. Pressing update did not help either:
[image: Project is marked as being on the profile]

Even though it is not there:
[image: No open source projects listed]

I also already tried disconnecting my Careers profile from GitHub and reconnecting it, but got the same result. It's still marked as being on my profile when it's not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache and retry. It might help.

Comment: @Creator Just tried it in a fresh incognito session and still got the same issue

Comment: Hi, we've deployed a new fix - can you verify this works now? thx for reporting!

Comment: @mythz Nice one. I can confirm that it's now possible to add projects that were previously removed